# What does CR 1/2 mean for Summoned Creature: Eagle?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

What does CR 1/2 mean for [Summoned Creature: Eagle](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/birds/eagle/summoned-creature-eagle/)?

The first line is:

> Eagle CR 1/2

Comment: Related: [How do I use CR?](/questions/70862), [Reducing a monster below CR 1](/questions/24496), [Using the bestiary](/questions/35219)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CR is Challenge Rating. Oddly enough, there is no such term in the PF [glossary](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary/).

See the [Gamemastering](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/#Step_2Determine_Challenge_Rating_CR) section for the CR definition:

> #### Step 2—Determine Challenge Rating (CR)
>
> ***Challenge Rating*** (or CR) is a convenient number used to indicate the relative danger presented by a monster, trap, hazard, or other encounter—the higher the CR, the more dangerous the encounter. Refer to [Table: Encounter Design](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/#Table-Encounter-Design) to determine the Challenge Rating your group should face, depending on the difficulty of the challenge you want and the group’s APL.